# Call several functions and return the collective result

Tags: python, design-patterns

I want to call some functions to a single value and return the collective result.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i

    def get(self):
        return self.fn1(self.fn2(self.i)) #200

    def fn1(self, i):
        return i + i #10+10 = 20

    def fn2(self, i):
        return i * i #20*20 = 200

    #...

foo = Foo(10)
print(foo.get())
```

Is there a more elegant way or pattern?

Comment: Not really.  What's wrong with this?

Comment: @S.Lott, Just not nice, especially if you add a few more methods like: `self.fn1(self.fn2(self.fn3(self.i)))`

Comment: I'm thinking of using a metaclass... but that's probably too "crazy" for such a simple thing.

Comment: I don't really see what the class wrapper is accomplishing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, nesting functions as you do above is the most straightforward and readable way to compose functions in Python.

If you're composing *many* functions, it *might* be worth writing a `compose` function.

```
def compose(*funcs):
    if len(funcs) == 1:
        return funcs[0]
    else:
        def composition(*args, **kwargs):
            return funcs[0](compose(*funcs[1:])(*args, **kwargs))
        return composition
```

Or, if you prefer an iterative over a recursive solution:

```
def compose_pair(f1, f2):
    def composition(*args, **kwargs):
        return f1(f2(*args, **kwargs))
    return composition

def compose_iterative(*funcs):
    iterfuncs = iter(funcs)
    comp = next(iterfuncs)
    for f in iterfuncs:
        comp = compose_pair(comp, f)
    return comp
```

Comment: You're absolutely right, I meant a _composition_ with a _variable number of arguments_

Answer (score 3):

Here is my try to improve this a little bit.

```
def fn1(i):
    return i + i #10+10 = 20

def fn2(i):
    return i * i #20*20 = 200

def get(i):
    funcs = [fn2, fn1]
    for f in funcs:
        i = f(i)
    return i

print(get(10))
```

Comment: Yes, it's the first thing that occurred to me as well. Not sure, but may be easier with decorators?

Comment: @tomas: Definitely not easier. I can't think of a way to use decorators nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, two of my favorite python functions are map and reduce.

```
def get(i):
    return reduce(lambda acc, f: f(acc), [i,fn2,fn1] )

def fn1(i):
    return i + i #10+10 = 20

def fn2(i):
    return i * i #20*20 = 200

print( get(10) ) # 200
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a decorator-style solution:

```
class Base()

    def __init__(self, decorated):
       self.decorates = decorated

    def foo(self, arg):
        if self.decorates:
            arg = self.decorates.foo( arg )

        return self._do_foo( arg )

    def _do_foo(self, arg):
       return arg
```

Your implementations will inherit from Base and implement _do_foo().
You set it up like this:

```
a = Subclass(None)
b = AnotherSublcass( a )
c = YetAnotherSubclass( b )
```

all of the Sublcasses inherit from Base. when you call c.foo( arg ), you'll get the result passed through all three _do_foo() methods.